# PHPUnit v.4+ mocking static methods

Tags: phpunit

I have following class with one method:

```
class A 
{
    public function my( $myParam )
    {       
        \modelClass::truncateTable('table_name');

        return $myParam * 4;            
    }   
}
```

Is it possible to mock static method "truncateTable"? I want to make sure it was called once in "my" method. PHPUnit version 4.5, so "staticExpects" is no longer available in this version (depending this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357001/phpunit-mock-objects-and-static-methods)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPUnit Mock Objects and Static Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357001/phpunit-mock-objects-and-static-methods)

Comment: Can't be done in your case.  You could only mock static methods within the same class and that is not available in your version of PHPUnit

Answer (score -1):

You can use Proxy class that will wrap your static calls.

```
class ProxyModel{
   public function truncateTable($tableName){
      \modelClass::truncateTable($tableName);
   }
}
```

After that in the Class that you are using the static call use your proxy class method instead.

```
class A{
   private $model;

   public function __construct(ProxyModel $model){
      $this->model = $model;
   }

   public function my(){
      $this->model->truncateModel("table_name");
   }

}
```

Now you can easily mock the proxy class and pass it as dependency to your class.

Comment: This answer is useless because it requires the code under test to be modified.