# PHP Unit - Mock Class

Tags: php, phpunit

How to mock class method `getResult()` ?

```
use App\ExampleClass;


$res = ExampleClass::getResult();
```

What I tried so far, and it didn't work:

```
$this->exampleClass = $this->getMockBuilder('App\ExampleClass')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();


$this->exampleClass->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getResult')
    ->willReturn(true);
```

Comment: Mocking static methods seems to have been possible but also seems to have been removed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357001/phpunit-mock-objects-and-static-methods and https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/77 give more info.

Comment: Mocking static methods is not supported: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.2/test-doubles.html

"Please note that final, private, and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit’s test double functionality and retain their original behavior except for static methods that will be replaced by a method throwing a \PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\BadMethodCallException exception."

Comment: It is not working... How?

Comment: this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/62757723/7594704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHPUnit` will ignore mocking static methods:

> Please note that final, private, and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit’s test double functionality and retain their original behavior except for static methods that will be replaced by a method throwing a `\PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\BadMethodCallException exception.`

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.2/test-doubles.html?highlight=static#test-doubles

You can't do it with PHPUnit’s `phpunit-mock-objects` library. Seek to the alternative - [**Mockery**](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/):

```
$this->exampleClassMock = \Mockery::mock('overload:App\ExampleClass');

$this->exampleClassMock
  ->shouldReceive('getResult')
  ->once()
  ->andReturn(true);
```

Comment: You cannot use `phpunit-mock-objects` with current versions of PHPUnit.